# Meaning of $\int_{x_0}^{x} P(x,y) dx$ since $x$ is a variable

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, notation

I am following Morris-tenenbaum ordinary differential equation which has the proof for the sufficient condition for the exactness of a DE,
Given,  $\frac{\partial {f(x,y)}}{\partial {x}} = P(x,y)$,
$\frac{\partial {f(x,y)}}{\partial {y}} = Q(x,y)$
So, $f(x,y)=\int_{x_0}^{x} P(x,y) dx +R(y)$
I do not get what exactly what this integration would mean since it is integrating from a constant to a variable.

Comment: I think it is poor notation on one part as the limits of the integral should not normally be written as the same as the integration variable. All this is saying is that the function is equal to the integral of its derivative at a point x, taking into account boundary conditions

Comment: This is probably bad notation for $\int_{x_0}^{x} P(x',y)dx'$

Comment: but later in the proof, when the equation becomes ,  $\int_{x_0}^{x}\frac{\partial Q(x,y)}{\partial x}dx +R'(y)=Q(x,y)$ , which further becomes $Q(x,y)-Q(x_0,y)+R'(x,y)=Q(x,y)$  it is concluded that $R'(x,y)=Q(x_0,y)$, so i dont get what the integral would mean...

Comment: Many books use this kind of "mathematical slang" - one and same letter have different meanings in one and same text depending on context. No other way to keep context in mind and work. Or rewrite that text with new variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that $P$ and $Q$ are defined all over the place. We are looking for a function $$f:\>(x,y)\mapsto f(x,y)\in{\mathbb R}$$
satisfying
$${\partial f\over\partial x}=P(x,y),\quad {\partial f\over\partial y}=Q(x,y)\qquad\forall\,(x,y)\ .$$
At this point the author makes the *Ansatz*
$$f(x,y):=\int_{x_0}^xP(t,y)\>dt+g(y)\ ,\tag{1}$$
with a new unknown function $g$ which depends on only one variable.

For any given $x_0$ and $y$ the integral $\int_{x_0}^xP(t,y)\>dt$ is well defined, and depends on $x$. You can think of it in the following way: The function $P$, depending on $x$ and the "parameter" $y$, is integrated  along the horizontal segment going from $(x_0,y)$ to $(x,y)$.

The question now is: Can a function $f$ of the "special form" $(1)$ solve the given problem, when $g$ is chosen suitably? This question is dealt with on the succeeding lines of your book, I hope.